# SingleEmailMessage: adding a name and address on setReplyTo

Tags: singleemailmessage

When sending emails, I'm using the mail.setReplyTo() method to provide the Reply-To address:

```
...
mail.setReplyTo('replyme@company.com');
...
```

Which results on the next email sent (headers):

```
From: Company <some@company.com>
Reply-To: replyme@company.com
To: "customer@gmail.com" <customer@gmail.com>
```

So, when the customer hits Reply, the To field gets populated with the Reply-To address. **Is there a way to provided also a name to show up on the To field when the client hits reply?** In other words, is there a way to have this headers on the email sent?

```
From: Company <some@company.com>
Reply-To: Customer Requests <replyme@company.com>
To: "customer@gmail.com" <customer@gmail.com>
```

I've tried to specify the Name like this:

```
...
mail.setReplyTo('Name <replyme@company.com>');
...
```

but raises the next exception:

```
    SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid replyTo address: Name <replyme@company.com>: []
```

Couldn't find any way to do it on the Salesforce documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setSenderDisplayName. Your code will look something like this:

```
mail.setReplyTo('replyme@company.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Customer Requests');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Trying to specify the name with setSenderDisplayName raises this exception because I'm already using a Org Wide email address: `SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_SENDER_DISPLAY_NAME, When an org-wide Email Address ID is specified, a sender display name may not be specified.: [senderDisplayName, Test Org Account Team]`

Comment: Yes this error is expected if you are attempting to use both setSenderDisplayName() & setOrgWideEmailAddress(). Your question does not include the logic you have for creating this SingleEmailMessage. Can you provide your code?

Comment: This is a wrong answer. setSenderDisplayName is about the From header. setReplyTo is about the Reply-To header. I would still be interested in a correct answer.